# AlertDialog.Builder style on Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to modify AlertDialog.Builder's title and body style.
Son I use setCustomTitle and setView to arrive this.
Below is the simplify code:

```
private AlertDialog dialog;
public void Showdialog() {
    LayoutInflater inflaterTitle = getLayoutInflater();
    View TitleView = inflaterTitle.inflate(layout, (ViewGroup)findViewById(id));
    TextView Title = (TextView)TitleView.findViewById(id);
    Title.setText("Title");

    LayoutInflater inflaterBody = getLayoutInflater();
    View BodyView = inflaterBody.inflate(layout, (ViewGroup)findViewById(id));
    TextView Body = (TextView)BodyView.findViewById(id);
    Body.setText("Body");

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCustomTitle(TitleView);
    builder.setView(BodyView);

    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

The TitleView and BodyView with bule background.
The show dialog as below.
[image]
There contain 2 black.
How can I remove it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of that, if you want to have custom layout for dialog then use below code.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SplashActivity.this,R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
        dialog.getWindow();
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.internet_dialog);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        Button retryBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.retryBtn);
        Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);

        retryBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                checkForInternetAndNextFlow();
            }
        });

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
```

**styles.xml in Values resouces:**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>

    <!-- <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:background">#00000000</item> -->

</style>
```

This will help you a lot. You can set any view as per your need.

Answer (score 3):

Try Dialog with custom layout as following...

**res/layout/main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonShowCustomDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Custom Dialog" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**res/layout/custom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>/>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Ok "
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;
    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShowCustomDialog);

        // add button listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // custom dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
            dialog.setTitle("Title...");

            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
          }
        });
    }
}
```