# Show Image in AlertDialog?

Tags: android, image, android-alertdialog

How can I show an image when I open an `AlertDialog`?

Or is there any other way to show an image except `ImageView`?

I got this code, but it's only showing text and I can't seem to find way to show an image:

```
private void AlertDialogz() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alert.setTitle("Note");
    alert.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.lyrics));
    alert.setCancelable(false);
    alert.setPositiveButton("Zatvori", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18504788/1066839

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276501/how-to-put-an-image-in-an-alertdialog-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build everything you want into a layout of some kind like a LinearLayout, either programmatically or in XML that you inflate at runtime.
Then use the AlterDialog.Builder's setView method to assign that layout to the dialog.

```
LinearLayout imageLayout;
imageLayout.addView(myImageView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams());
dialog.setView(imageLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
       alert.setTitle("Note");
       alert.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.lyrics));
       alert.setCancelable(false);
       alert.setPositiveButton("Zatvori", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
});
```